# Limitar quantidade de páginas em paginação PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma paginação em PHP e MYSQLI, e gostaria de que os link das páginas em baixo fosse limitado, por exemplo:

Paginas: 1 2 3 4 5 (vai até 100), apareça somente as primeira 5, se eu tiver na página 10, me mostra 8 9 10 11 12, não sei se me entenderam, mas o que me acontece é que tenho bastante itens adiconados no banco e o que acontece é que aparece mais de 200 paginas, e eu quero que mostra os links de pelo menos 5. Segue o código:

```
<?php
            $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; 

            $banco = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE empresa='1' AND ativo='1'"); 

            $total = mysqli_num_rows($banco); 

            $registros = 10;

            $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

            $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros; 

            $banco = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE empresa='1' AND ativo='1' LIMIT $inicio,$registros"); 
            $total = mysqli_num_rows($banco); 

            while($exibe_pecas = mysqli_fetch_array($banco)) { 
        ?>
        <div class="conteudo_p">
            <div class="codigo_p"><?php echo $exibe_pecas['codigo']; ?></div>
            <div class="nome_p"><?php echo $exibe_pecas['nome']; ?></div>
            <div class="quantidade_p"><?php echo $exibe_pecas['qtde_estoque']; ?></div>
            <div class="preco_p">R$ <?php echo $exibe_pecas['prc_venda']; ?></div>
            <div class="acao_p">#</div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
            if($pagina > 1) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".($pagina - 1)."' class='controle'>&laquo; anterior</a>";
            }

            for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas; $i++) {
                $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
                echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>";
            }

            if($pagina < $numPaginas) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".($pagina + 1)."' class='controle'>proximo &raquo;</a>";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa limitar isso no **for**:

```
$margemDireita = 2;
$margemEsquerda = ($pagina > 2) ? 2 : 0;

for ($i = $pagina - $margemEsquerda; $i < $pagina + $margemDireita; $i++) {
   $ativo = ($i == $pagina) ? 'numativo' : '';
   echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=".$i."' class='numero ".$ativo."'> ".$i." </a>";
}
```

**Entendendo a lógica:** Foram criadas variáveis para setar quantas páginas pra esquerdas, e quantas pra direita. Então o for se limita a começar o **$i** a **2** números antes da página atual, e finalizar o for **2** números depois da página atual.
Ex: página atual é 5, o for iniciaria em 3 (5-2=3) e acabaria em 7 (5+2=7), resultado: 3 4 **5** 6 7